# In Xtext, How to define terminal with same definition? Or Circumvent EString requirement in crosslinking?

Tags: parsing, grammar, xtext

I have the following grammar defined in XText.

```
Object:
    "object" (name=INT)? ("extends" superType=[Object|INT] "{" 
        (comps+=Component)* 
    "}"
;
```

I'm having problems defining the cross-reference since apparently `INT` does not return an `ecore::EString` object.

I tried defining an `STRINT` terminal:

```
STRINT returns ecore::EString:
    INT
;
```

However this hides the INT terminal previously defined, which is another problem.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to define a new terminal with the same pattern as another and not hide the first one?
- Are there workarounds for this `ecore::Estring` issue, because I want to use an integer for crosslinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you define STRINT as a data type rule, it'll not hide another terminal. So basically what you described will work:

```
STRINT:
  INT
;
```